# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy'

Tags: python, command-line

I am attempting to use blender from the command line including bpy functions using https://pypi.org/project/bpy/

I have completed a pip installation and have had no errors or warnings, however when I try to run a script I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy'. I had this working on a previous machine but have not been able to get this working on my current machine (Im assuming im missing a step).

I have downgraded to python 3.7.6 and pip version 20.2.4, I was able to install bpy version - 2.82.1 by pip install bpy (I followed an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178840/cannot-install-package-bpy-using-pip).

I then also followed the advice of https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy/issues/13, which is an issue I recognized from the last time I tried to get this working.

I am using windows (as I did on the previous install which worked). Im wondering if im missing something in path or similar. I have checked and my conda environment (base environment) lists bpy as an installed package, yet it cant be found.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have checked and my bpy install (2.82) is in the location where the python.exe is for the environment (base) im using (so maybe not a path issue?)

Answer (score 0):

After multiple hours of searching, the issue was due to the python interpreter not being automatically changed when activating a different environments within visual studio code.

The bpy module must use python 3.7.6 (for my version anyway) otherwise the module is not found.